# VBA check if distinct values from 2 fields match

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, vba, ms-access

I'm VERY new to VBA but have some coding experience so I'm slowly starting to learn. I have two tables in my access database that each have one field that is the same. One table is a distinct list of the possible values ("TOSITEXREF")that could show up in the same field on the other table ("Trans_Earned"). This function I am trying to create will run in a macro to figure out whether or not the data that is being appended via queries has an instance in the ToLocn field that is not on the list of possible values. Here is what I have so far, but is not working:

```
Function TESTING()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TransEarned")

Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TOSITEXREF")

Dim cond1A As Boolean

cond1A = (rs.Fields("ToLocn") = rs2.Fields("ToLoc"))

If cond1A Then
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Earns", acViewNormal, acEdit
Else
    DoCmd.CancelEvent
    MsgBox "Unknown ToLocation, Please Update TOSITEXREF File to acccount for new location", vbOKOnly, "NEW LOCATION"
End If

Set rs = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: how are you looping through your recordsets? (sorry don't know a thing about vba but I think your recordset is multiple rows from each table so you have to iterate through them somehow)

Comment: I'd create a query that joins the tables together, then search the query for your intended value. If you have no rows in the recordset, then you don't have a match. conversely if you have 1 or more rows, there is a match.

Comment: @Jeremy I had no idea you could store sql statements in a string and then use that string to define the data for the recordset, your comment helped a ton and I figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Final VBA example that will return a value in the Loc field from table1 that does not show up in the Loc field of Table2:

```
Function Validate()

Dim sql As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

sql = "SELECT Table1.Loc FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Loc =  Table2.Loc WHERE (((Table2.Loc) Is Null))"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)

If (rs.RecordCount = 0) Then
     MsgBox "WORKS", vbkokonly, "WORKS"
Else
     MsgBox "DOES NOT WORK", vbkokonly, "DOES NOT WORK"

Set rs = Nothing

End If
End Function
```